# Equal height on dynamically added classes

Tags: html, jquery

I have an equal height script that runs by calling

```
$(".row1").equalCols();
$(".row2").equalCols();
```

the mark up is

```
    <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-row">
    <div class="item row1"></div>
<div class="item row1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-row">
    <div class="item row2"></div>
<div class="item row2"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This could have an infinite number of grid-rows & for each new grid-row the CMS increments the number appended to the row class.

I don't want to keep adding `$(".rowX").equalCols();` calls to my doc.ready function - I've been trying to find a class beginning with row and loop through them all in the equal height call - something like `$(".row[x]").equalCols();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all the `row1`, `row2` items has the class `item` use it

```
$(".grid-row > .item").equalCols();
```

---

Try

```
$(".grid-row").children(':first-child').each(function () {
    var row = this.className.match(/row\d+/)[0];
    $('.' + row).equalCols()
});
```

Comment: this doesn't quite work, and its my bad for not explaining correctly - i need to set height on items within each grid-row. this solution sets the same height to all items on the page (height taken from tallest item)

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code which will call 'equalCols' function for all elements having class  starts with row e.g - row1, row2 ....

```
$('[class^="row"]').each(function(index)
{
   equalcols();
});
```

Here inside function you can have instance of each div, which can be pass to your calling function like given in below example

```
$('[class^="row"]').each(function(index)
{
       equalcols(this);//here 'this' is the instance of current div
});

function equalcols(divInstance)
{
  $(divInstance).css('height',maxHeight);
}
```

This will set height of each div with class='rowX' to max height you want.